# Enable/Disable Console Window - C++

Tags: c++, console

I was wondering if there was a way to toggle the console from a C++ program? I use OpenGL, GLFW, and GLEW to create a graphical window, and I have a console in the background. Although it outputs some data, that data is being logged and I have a toggle button in my program to specify whether or not to output to the console or not, but even when the console isn't being used, it is still there. I try and keep all of my code as cross-compatible as possible, so platform-specific functions/librarys can't be used to disable the console.

My compiler is GCC( G++ ); I compile and link manually, I don't like IDE's

If there is some sort of cross-compatible library out there that can disable the console or a standard header that I could use, that would be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am currently coding on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, but I write my code to be cross-compatible between Windows, Mac, and Linux

Comment: You will probably have to write your own wrapper for platform specific calls. Windows has the `AllocConsole()` function that you might want to check out (following link). No idea of a *nix equivalent though. Also, this question is not about OpenGL or GLEW per se, so you might consider editing it and removing the OpenGL tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK, I thought that I should clarify that I was using a GUI so I wouldn't get any responses like: If it's a console program, why remove the console, etc. But I see your point, I'll remove it. Let me check that link out and I'll tell you the results.

Comment: On Linux, if you are running it from the terminal, you'd probably have to add something like **1>/dev/null 2>&1** at the end of the command.  The trace is always useful when debugging.